# django-autoslug doesn't work with filenames

Tags: python, django, slug

I use the django-autoslug package which does great work in most of the cases.

I have those fields in my model:

```
class Design(TimeStampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=180, unique=True, null=True, help_text="The name of your design")
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True)
```

When I have a title with the filename, such as: 
can.2015-01-14.02-54-37.stl, the generated slug is design-3 (apparently it doesn't manage to generate an autoslug for such names.

I'd be happy to hear your recommmendations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you is populating the slug-field with a field that contains the next options:

- null=True